# Is there any differences in what will be backed up between an encrypted and unencrypted Time Machine Backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine, encryption

I do make encrypted Time Machine backups to my Synology NAS which works exactly how I want it. But I recently had to restore from that backup and it's obviously very slow.
Since this was a planned restore I thought next time I'll do an unencrypted backup to my external SSD right before restoring and will have a much faster restore.

1. Am I right that restoring from an unencrypted backup will be faster?
2. Is there anything that Time Machine does not include into an unencrypted backup which would be included into an encrypted one?

Comment: The limiting factor is probably the network speed, rather than the encryption. I can't think of any reason why an [un]encrypted backup should leave stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

The restore time is not significantly different in my case between the two backups.

My old Synology was actually the bottleneck when compared to local USB 2 and USB 3 drives - LAN use was around 70% of max on the console (80%+ of max LAN speed is about the best I could ever get out of the Synology and I think that was fluke).

If speed is key then look to use something like Carbon Copy - I find both backups and restores faster with this than TimeMachine.